# Criteria for combining two list items

Tags: python

I am programming a personal assistant that supports voice. It can send emails, check the weather, and open websites.

I am using Google Voice API to convert my voice to speech. When I say "Open funny dot reddit dot com", Google recognizes it as 'Funny. Reddit.com". So I need a way to make it so anything before the '.', is combined with the string with .com.

```
text = ['open', 'funny.', 'Reddit.com']
if 'open' in text:
        print(text)
        text = text.split()
        sub = 'com'
        www = 'www'
        wcheck = ("\n".join(s for s in text if www in s))
        website = ("\n".join(s for s in text if sub in s))
        if 'www' in wcheck:
            web.open(website)
        if 'www' not in wcheck:
            web.open('www.' + website)
```

Comment: prefix = "\n".join(s for s in text if '%s.' in s)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to do actually. `prefix = "\n".join(s for s in text if '%s.' in s)` will join words or characters by a newline. Isn't your intention to create valid URLs?

Comment: My bad, I am just not sure what to do

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... You have some fixed strings; eg. "reddit.com". Then you have some rather dynamic strings that are returned from Google. You then want to combine these to make valid URLs. If that's the case, it would be nice to see examples of the strings that are returned from Google.

Comment: I did have the example (sorta). Google returns "open funny. Reddit.com", which I then split.

Comment: The code I have functions if I just say "open reddit.com"

Comment: Soo... Removing "open" from the beginning of the string and stripping out all the spaces would give you what you want? Eg, "open funny.  reddit.com" -> "funny.reddit.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to combine only list elements that meet certain criteria is to first create a smaller list that contains only the items which meet said criteria. In your case, this list would be `['funny.', 'Reddit.com']`. You can create this with a list comprehension:

```
[e for e in text if e.endswith((".",".com",".net",".org",".edu",".gov"))]
```

The full answer for your case: Try joining each element in that is part of the URL to make a complete URL.

```
URL = "".join([e for e in text if e.endswith((".",".com",".net",".org",".edu",".gov"))])
```

This covers most websites, I think. Example:

```
>>> text=["open","funny.","reddit.com"]
>>> print "".join([e for e in text if e.endswith((".",".com",".net",".org",".edu",".gov"))])
funny.reddit.com
```

Note that this only works well for simple cases, not cases like `["google.com", "open", "funny.", "reddit.com"]`, which would put out `"google.com.funny.reddit.com"`. I'm assuming all your inputs are relatively simple.